# Python based Instrument locks

Tags: python, shared, locks

I am running a program on 2 different PCs which control same power supply having 2 channels. which is connected with TCP . For talking to the power supply I am using vxi_11.

When i run same program on 2 Different PCs [I am trying to run 2 PCs at the same time as there is no shared resource]

They both talk to the power supply through 2 different TCPIp connection but what I am seeing is that I am getting the output of one PC on other.

I can use rlocks and all but due to the fact that these are two different programs running.

I want to have some external Lock mechanism , basically something OS can manage for me.

can anybody help me in this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could `flock` a file that was located a network mount accessible from both boxes.

i.e. something like:

```
import fcntl

# get the lock
with open('file.lock', 'w') as f:
    fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)

# now proceed to do stuff with the lock in place
```

Where `file.lock` is a full file path pointed to the network-mounted file. That will block as long as something else already has the exclusive lock. If you want more control over it, i.e. to timeout, log number of tries, etc. you can *bitwise OR* the `fcntl.LOCK_NB` flag with `LOCK_EX` -- that is, `fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB` -- and do so in a loop, breaking when you get access to the lock; an `IOError` exception is raised when a non-blocking lock would be blocked).

[More flock Info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock)